# Loading a page via a comment link and clicking 'edit (1)' to review a suggested edit makes the page scroll to the comment again

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, hyperlinks

When going to a comment directly, I noticed that when you hit the edit button, the page scrolls back to that comment instead of leaving focus on the edit window popup. This leads to an almost black site, and a weird user experience where they have to scroll back to the top in order to do anything.

Steps to reproduce:

- Goto [Bulk Update / Replace mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51345980/bulk-update-replace-mysql/51346045?noredirect=1#comment89666627_51346045) (Or, if the pending edit is no longer there, head to any link to a comment of an answer down the page.)
- Click edit:
  [image]
- The page scrolls to the bottom of the page, instead of staying at the top in focus of the popup.